# Downloading owned "app" content that is on device

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to download one of my apps content from the iPhone with the XCode 4 organizer.

So I open the organizer,
select "Applications",
select the app from which I want to download content,
and click download.

Then I ask to save the content into a folder on the desktop.
At this time, XCode says : "The operation header was invalid".

The content of the created folder only shows the "Library" folder, perhaps everything in it is not complete. Some of downloaded files can't be opened.

So... How may I fix this to be able to download my app "content" ?

Note : I don't have the exact project that was used to create the app anymore. I have renamed the app (and also of course the folder, the files, ... of the app), and continued the project with this new name.

The reason I'd like to do this is to get the files created on the iPhone with the old version of the installed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a way to get this working just now. Sorry for posting my comment as an answer, where is the comment button??

The way I got this working was by first ending my app from running in the background.  Next I restarted XCode and unlocked my phone (mine is protected by a pass code).  Then I simply tried to get the data again and it came across.

Please let me know if this worked for you !!

~Arash

P.S.Seriously, I can't find the comment button :( lol

Comment: @user733464 : I'll try. For the comment button, search "add comment" on this page.

Comment: you need some reputation to be able to comment